# change grid layout based on generic container size (not using classes)

Tags: html, css

In the following example I have two containers for a flex item. When the container is 300px I want the two 150px boxes to be side by side (as seen in the example). When the container is 150 however I'd like to change the container display to `block` to have them stacked on each other (we shouldn't see the yellow below).

Is it possible to write CSS WITHOUT leveraging the example_1 or example_2 classes and just referencing their container? I tried Chromes `@container` query but this didn't work... any help appreciated!!

```css
.example_1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.example_2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-thing {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: max-content;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.flex-thing .item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example_1">
  <div class="flex-thing">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="example_2">
  <div class="flex-thing">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the red box to auto wrap down to second line, you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container. or you can add

```
.example_2 .flex-thing{
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to use css that queries the container and doesnt directly call `.example_2` or `.example_1` since these containers will be generated elsewhere - perhaps that isn't possible?